# Webm video files recorded on Chrome Mobile cannot be converted to MP4

Tags: node.js, typescript, ffmpeg, video-processing, mediarecorder

I have a website where I record the user's webcam via the MediaRecorder API.
The video stream is created with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia():

```js
// Create stream
const cameraStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: 
  { 
    aspectRatio: 1/1, 
    facingMode: 'user',
    width: { min: 360, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
    height: { min: 360, ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
    deviceId: undefined
  }  
});

// Add stream to videoElement to display a video preview
videoElement.srcObject = cameraStream;
```

I then check which mime types are available in the browser and use that info to initialize the MediaRecorder:

```js
const validMimeTypes = [
  "video/webm\;codecs=vp8",
  "video/webm\;codecs=daala",
  "video/webm\;codecs=h264",
  "video/webm",
  "video/mpeg"
];

const getFirstAvailableMimeType = () => {
  for (const mimeType of validMimeTypes) {
    if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(mimeType)) {
      return mimeType;
    }
  }
}

// Initialize Media Recorder
const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(cameraStream, {
  mimeType: getFirstAvailableMimeType(),
});
```

After I finish recording a video, I upload it to a server and store it on Firebase Storage, so it can be downloaded later.

After downloading a video, I would like to convert it to an MP4 file. I've tried using CloudConvert and HandBrake. Both services have no issues converting videos that were recorded via Chrome on my desktop, but both fail when I try to convert videos recorded via Chrome Mobile on my phone.

When trying to convert the video to MP4 via CloudConvert, the following error is shown:

```
EBML header parsing failed. /input/import1/69fcceaccc27a0d6eabcb8a65045e87e.webm Invalid data found when processing input
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Download a **hex editor** for your desktop and check the WebM bytes from mobile. Compare the first line of mobile bytes to first line of other (working) video bytes from desktop... PS: Is your phone an iOS device by any chance?

Comment: @VC.One Great suggestion! By using a hex editor I realised I was downloading a response object blob instead of the webm video itself. Now I have no idea how the videos from Chrome could be converted in the first place. Anyway, thank you!